# CentOS7 YUM proxy authentication failed

Tags: centos, yum, proxy

I've stumbled across a little problem with my CentOS7 server. It's a virtual server behind a proxy and it can connect to the internet, but it can't use yum. Whenever I try, I get the error:

```
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/? 
release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=stock error was
14: HTTP Error 407 - Proxy Authentication Required
```

Even though I have the proxy configured in **/etc/environment**:

```
http_proxy='http://user:password@url:8088/'
HTTP_PROXY='http://user:password@url:8088/'
https_proxy='http://user:password@url:8088/'
HTTPS_PROXY='http://user:password@url:8088/'
ftp_proxy='http://user:password@url:8088/'
FTP_PROXY='http://user:password@url:8088/'
no_proxy='localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,*.localdomain.com,*.bl.ch,10.*'
NO_PROXY='localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,*.localdomain.com,*.bl.ch,10.*'
```

and in **/etc/yum.conf**:

```
proxy=http://url:8088/
proxy_username=user_name
proxy_password=password
```

I even declared it in **/root/.bash_profile**:

```
export http_proxy="http://url:8088/"
```

and in **/etc/wgetrc**:

```
 http_proxy='http://user:password@url:8088/'
 HTTP_PROXY='http://user:password@url:8088/'
 https_proxy='http://user:password@url:8088/'
 HTTPS_PROXY='http://user:password@url:8088/'
 ftp_proxy='http://user:password@url:8088/'
 FTP_PROXY='http://user:password@url:8088/'
 no_proxy='localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,*.localdomain.com,*.bl.ch,10.*'
 NO_PROXY='localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,*.localdomain.com,*.bl.ch,10.*'
```

I really don't get how it's still missing the authentication; has anyone an idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Can you get out onto the www via the proxy using any other services i.e. with curl?

Comment: I can curl google, but not http://mirrorlist.centos.org. So I guess I have a failing repository active, I'll try and comment if it solve the problem. Thanks a lot for the hint, didn't think of it:)

Comment: I just have the base repo enabled, so still having the problem.

Comment: @origins523: Can you provide some more specific information regarding your company proxy? Maybe the `curl` you have used? How applications authenticate there in general? Is it a NTLMv2 proxy (e.g. is `curl` option `--proxy-ntlm` used)? etc. ...

Comment: they changed some network configuration in our company environment, now we have to add the domain like this COM\ in front of the proxyuser in our yum.config. thanks anyway a lot for the help:)